# Properties of dot products. Some missing in my book and proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why does $2v \cdot 3u = 6(v \cdot u)$

[image]

It's not in the properties here:

[image]

If we're using property 3 in reverse... it can be done factor at a time? Is this what is going on:

$$6(u \cdot v) = 3(2u \cdot v) = (2u \cdot 3v)$$

So is it being used twice?

Also in the this proof of the length of a scalar multiple, why are you allowed to pull out the c from under the square root out into an absolute value? What rules governs this?

[image]

Comment: yes, you have to use one of the properties you posted twice

Comment: show me a bit? Please?

Comment: It is most certainly in the properties listed.

Comment: The dot (or scalar) product is bilinear.

Comment: Oh I see.... you can pull out pieces of the scalar, factor by factor?

Comment: @Exodd edited. Is what I wrote right?

Comment: yes. If you want the more formal way, it is
$$
6(u\cdot v) = 3(2(u\cdot v)) = 3(2u\cdot v) = 2u\cdot 3v
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\vec a\cdot\vec b=\|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta$$

then for $\lambda,\mu>0$,

$$(\lambda\vec a)\cdot(\mu\vec b)=\|\lambda a\|\|\mu b\|\cos\theta=\lambda\mu\|a\|\|b\|\cos\theta=\lambda\mu\,\vec a\cdot\vec b.$$

---

The property also holds for negative factors, but you may have to take the antisupplement of $\theta$.